# Not able to filter check by bill reference number in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am integrating acumatica in my software and I need to void bill.
To void bill I need to void check.
Can any help me how to get check by bill reference nbr in acumatica REST API

Answer (score 0):

You can pull it based on the applications of the bill. We will use bill # 000007 as an example.

Make your GET request: http://localhost/dev/entity/Default/20.200.001/Bill/Bill/000007?$expand=Applications

It would return the bill amount (in this case 325) and then the check with the amount paid. You would get it by Applications => Array => ReferenceNbr

```
{
    "id": "xxxxx-ba7f-ec11x-xxx-xxxxx",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "Amount": {
        "value": 325.0000
    },
    "Applications": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxxx-7ba0-ec11-b83e-xxxxx",
            "rowNumber": 1,
            "note": null,
            "AmountPaid": {
                "value": 325.0000
            },
            "Balance": {
                "value": 0.0000
            },
            "DocType": {
                "value": "Check"
            },
            "ReferenceNbr": {
                "value": "000006"
            },
            "Status": {
                "value": "Closed"
            },
            "custom": {}
        }
    ],
```

From there, you can run the action on the check to void it
[image: add check from acumatica]